# Install Linux on Magellan GPS

Tags: system-installation, gps

I have an old Magellan RoadMate 5235T-LM GPS running Windows CE 6.0. The GPS doesn't really work anymore, so I am hoping to revive it by scrubbing Windows CE and installing Ubuntu or some other Linux distro on it. I haven't been able to find anything useful on the internet about how to do this, although I'm sure that it is possible (though not necessarily straightforward). Does anyone happen to know of some ways to do this, or some websites that may be helpful?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Although technically "not impossible", in practice it certainly is.

Comment: I don't think there will be much benefit. Windows CE GPSes are usually quite underpowered, typically old, use armv6 architectures and so forth. If you wish to run alternative GPS software, you can use something like [MioPocket](https://hackaday.com/tag/mio/), which allows you to access other Windows CE-based GPS software as well as the Windows CE Explorer. This allows you to run any Windows CE program. If Linux is your goal – it's incredibly difficult: there used to be a program called HaRET which could load a Linux kernel from Windows CE, but you have to have a compatible kernel.